# Data Structures and their Database Mapping in .Net

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, data-structures, mapping

From what I know, complex data structures (tree, binary tree, graph) are not available in the .Net Framework Base Class Library. Is there a good 3rd party library available for this purpose?

Further, I need to map these data structures back to a physical database (SQL Server). Is such an extension available? I'd love to have a tool to generate a script for database against the data structure I create (say a graph).

Needless to say, my data structures will shrink & grow. This should be reflected back in the database (therefore DMLs will be part of data structures to database mapping))

Answer (score 2):

Can you define "complex data structures"?  I've never found something that could be represented in SQL that couldn't be represented in .NET.

It sounds like you're just looking for an ORM for some forms over data.  Take a look at [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx).  They essentially help you create a mapping graph between business objects and data persistence.

Comment: Data Structures like tree, binary tree, graph ... I'm not looking for an ORM really ... I'm looking for data structures library that will end-to-end handle mapping of structure in memory and then in the database. Since the data structures are standard (or so do I think) I am assuming there would be something to address this out of the box.